# Celery and Django - No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, celery

I use instructions described [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). Python 2.7 and Celery 3.1.17.

In celery.py I have (in beginning):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
```

When I run:

```
celery -A proj worker -l info
```

I have an error:

```
from django.conf import settings
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

But I have Django and my project works.

How to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your project really named "proj"?

Comment: @MarkR. no, I change it here

Comment: Please install both Django and Celery packages under same virtualenv, so they can see each other installation: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/projects.html#virtualenv

Comment: Also might be circular import in settings.py or somewhere related

Comment: it looks on celery for Python 3. thanks!

Comment: Make sure that you're running celery with active virtualenv, if you're using any for django project.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are running `celery` with your `virtualenv`. The way to check this is with your `virtualenv` activated, run the command:

```
which celery
```

If you see something like:

```
/usr/bin/celery
```

Then you have `celery` installed globally, and you need to uninstall it, and make sure it's only in your `virtualenv`.

After uninstalling `celery` globally, within the `virtualenv` run `which celery` again and check.

Comment: This is not the problem. I have both Django and Celery installed in my virtualenv, and I also get this error.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I had `kombu.transport.django` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.  I was initially using Django as the transport agent, but when I upgraded to the latest Celery version, which does not support Django as a transport agent, I still had `kombu.transport.django` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.  When I removed that reference, I no longer got this error when starting celery.