# Celery-Django as Daemon: ImportError: No module named django.conf

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am working on Django project which uses Celery. In development, Celery is working fine. My tasks are getting scheduled properly in development. For Daemon, I have created **/etc/init.d/celeryd** and **/etc/defaults/celeryd** as per documentation. When I enter command  **bash -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start**, I got error N**o module named django.conf**

Here is my celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'axonatorprj.settings')

app = Celery('axonatorprj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

app.conf.update(
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Here is my celeryd:

```
# Names of nodes to start
#   most will only start one node:
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
#   but you can also start multiple and configure settings
#   for each in CELERYD_OPTS (see `celery multi --help` for examples).
CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="axonatorprj"
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/projects/axonator"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# %N will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists, e.g. nobody).
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="axonatorprj.settings"
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/projects/axonator
```

Comment: i think error is `env` based.So post your `celeryd` details

Comment: might help this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538903/celery-and-django-no-module-named-django

Comment: If you're using virtualenv, you might have to activate, before running the command.

Comment: I have edited question. This time I have added celeryd configuration file. Please Have a look

Comment: No I am not using virtual envoirnment. It is globalized

Comment: From experience I would strongly recommend using `supervisord` instead of init scripts to manage celery workers - https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/3.1/extra/supervisord/

Comment: I had used the same in my last attempt. In supervisord log, I got the same error.

Comment: where is django installed?

Comment: and where is django.conf?

Comment: When I entered locate django-admin I got this output,

/root/django-trunk/django/bin/django-admin.py
/root/django-trunk/docs/man/django-admin.1
/root/django-trunk/docs/ref/django-admin.txt
/usr/local/bin/django-admin
/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py

Comment: @GauravBagul did you solve this? If so, can you post an answer? I'm currently having the same issue. Kind regards.

Comment: @AaronLelevier I solved this by using systemctl method of deamonization. It is very easy to go with.